# Ruby - Assigning variable only when result is not false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To be specific, my problem arose when i was reading the source code of the has_secure_password and finally the authentication method.

```
def authenticate(unencrypted_password)
    BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest) == unencrypted_password && self
end
```

I want to have an instance variable that holds the user but only when the result of the authentication method returns the user and not false.

```
unless @user = user.authenticate(...)
  ...
end
```

Now i want to access the @user variable in methods called later. I tried to use the safe navigation operator but it only works if @user is nil and not false. Basically i dont want to check if @user is false when i call a method on the user. The method should not getting called when operate on a unauthenticated user. Is there a short way of writing such statements or do i need to check if @user is false every time?

Comment: `(@user = user.authenticate(...) || nil)` ? If authenticated successfully it will return the user object, else it will return false which with `||` short-circuit to give RHS (`nil`)

Comment: @kiddorails is it better to wrap this statement in a seperate method or should it stay in the controller like it is?

Comment: what is `user` (loca variable) before this call? seems like `@user = user if user.authenticate(#...)` would be sufficient. Would it not?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes it is a local variable. I looked for a chainable way of expressing it without writing too much of code. Thats why i asked if it would make sense to define a method for it. So that i can write `@user = user.authenticate_or_nil(...)` and i can call all other methods with the safe navigator `@user&.methodA(..)`.

Comment: A bit more context might be useful as I am not sure I understand why you would even need to call anything on an unauthenticated "user". Either way my suggestion would work as expected

Comment: @engineersmnky the context is rails before_action callback. I have a `:check_authentication` callback which basically just finds the user from the parameters (thats the local variable) and checks if the user is authenticated. Furthermore i have some before_action callbacks that only should run when i have an authenticated user. They require the `@user` instance variable. I dont want to check there every time if the user is authenticated. Also i want to avoid a `@is_authenticated` instance variable.

Comment: Right my suggestion was to halt the additional events if the user is not authenticated e.g. `redirect_to`

Comment: `Statements after redirect_to in our controller get executed, so redirect_to doesn't stop the execution of the function. To terminate the execution of the function immediately after the redirect_to, use return` Thats the reason i avoid redirect_to.

Comment: To each their own that seems like a lot of work around to avoid `redirect_to xxx and return`. Good luck :)